Late 80s/90s Sci-Fi thriller - Pregnant couple kidnapped and taken to underground facility
Here’s what I remember: The movie opens with a pregnant couple kidnapped at a police checkpoint on a highway at night. 
They wake up in an underground facility (similar to The Island.) Many other pregnant couples are there. 
All the men are separated from the women. From what I remember they were doing experiments on the women and injected the men with something they could activate that would cause them pain in case they got out of hand. 
I don’t remember what else happened except for the escape. They come of the facility and a Hispanic prisoners helps them but I think he died too. 

Probably Fortress (1993) with Christopher Lambert

In a dystopian 2017, ex-army officer John Henry Brennick and his wife Karen are attempting to cross the Canada–United States border to Vancouver to have a second child. Strict one-child policies forbid a second pregnancy, even after their firstborn has died, so Karen wears a magnetic vest to trick the security scanners. A guard notices and raises the alarm.
Brennick is caught, believing Karen to have escaped, and sentenced to 31 years at the Fortress, a private maximum security prison run by the Men-Tel Corporation. To maintain discipline all inmates are implanted with "Intestinators" which induce severe pain or death as a form of physical control and mental conditioning. The prison is co-run by Director Poe, who oversees Zed-10, a computer that monitors day-to-day activities. 
The prison is located underground, in the middle of the desert, inside a deep pit that can only be crossed by a retractable bridge, while the prisoners are kept in overcrowded cells secured by laser walls.
Wikipedia



The original ending of Fortress has been edited from some versions of the film. After reaching Mexico, Brennick, his wife, and Gomez end up at a barn where she starts going into labor. Gomez goes out to the truck to get a blanket for the soon-to-arrive baby. The Fortress computer manages to establish a remote linkup with the truck, overriding its internal controls. The truck suddenly comes to life and runs Gomez down, killing him. Brennick shoots the truck with the Strike Clone machine gun. He then sets it on fire with the flamethrower attachment. The truck crashes into the barn, exploding. Brennick climbs into the burning ruins to find his wife sitting against an old tractor, clutching her newborn baby.





THIS IS IT! Thank you so much!

You are welcome. Feel free to mark this answer as correct when time allows.
